Find a cyclic vertex-cut with fixed size
Let $G$ be a graph. A vertex subset $F \subset V(G)$ is a cyclic vertex-cut of $G$ if $G-F$ has at least two components containing cycles.  I plan to write a test to check if a graph $G$
contains a cyclic vertex cut of size  $k$.
(* Define function to check if a set is a cyclic vertex-cut *)
IsCycleCut[G_, S_] := 
 Module[{G1, subgraphs, cyclicSubgraphs},
  
  (* Use VertexDelete to remove the vertices in set S from the graph G *)
  G1 = VertexDelete[G, S];
  
  (* Compute all connected components (subgraphs not vertex sets) in G1 *)
  subgraphs = Map[Subgraph[G1, #] &, ConnectedComponents[G1]];
  
  (* Check each connected components if it contains a cycle (i.e., it is not acyclic) *)
  cyclicSubgraphs = Select[subgraphs, Not[AcyclicGraphQ[#]] &];
  
  (* If there are at least two connected components containing cycles, S is a cyclic vertex-cut*)
  If[Length[cyclicSubgraphs] > 1, Return[True], Return[False]]
]

(* Find a cyclic vertex-cut in the graph G *)
FindCycleCutSubset[G_, k_] := 
 Module[{subsets, result},
  
  (* Generate a k-sized subsets of vertices from the graph G *)
  subsets = Subsets[VertexList[G], {k}];
  
  (* Iterate over each subset and check if it is a cycle cut *)
  result = SelectFirst[subsets, IsCycleCut[G, #] &];
  
  (* If a valid cycle cut subset is found, return the subset; otherwise, return Null *)
  If[result === Missing["NotFound"], Return[Null], Return[result]]
]




g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 13, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 13, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 14, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 14, 13 \[UndirectedEdge] 14, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 15, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 15, 
   13 \[UndirectedEdge] 15, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 16, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 16, 13 \[UndirectedEdge] 16, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 17, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 17, 
   13 \[UndirectedEdge] 17, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 18, 
   10 \[UndirectedEdge] 18, 13 \[UndirectedEdge] 18, 
   10 \[UndirectedEdge] 19, 11 \[UndirectedEdge] 19, 
   13 \[UndirectedEdge] 19, 11 \[UndirectedEdge] 20, 
   12 \[UndirectedEdge] 20, 13 \[UndirectedEdge] 20}]
G1 = EdgeDelete[g, {10 <-> 18, 2 <-> 9, 13 <-> 19}]

AbsoluteTiming[FindCycleCutSubset[G1, 10]]

output: {75.0437, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 14, 20}}

It takes 75s. I would like to know if there is a better way to improve the approach.
Note  Since finding a cyclic vertex-cut with given size is enough,  Subsets may have better alternatives, such as iteration (which raises another question for me).

Your code defining G1 causes an error ("14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"). Please check.

Sorry. It should be EdgeDelete not VertexDelete. I have fixed it.

The following strategy & codes works for the sample graph $G_1$ you provided, but it might need modification for more complex graphs.
You require that $G-F$ has at least two components, each of which contains cycles. This implies that there are at least two cycles $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ in $G$, such that their edge distance is at least two. If $C_{1}$ is given, then $C_{2}$ must be a cycle in $G-N(C_{1})$, where $N(C_{1})$ is the neighborhood graph of $C_{1}$ in $G$.
In the case of your sample graph $G=G_1$, this condition is so strong that there is only one pair $(C_1, C_2)$ of such cycles, namely,
 {2 <-> 11, 11 <-> 19, 19 <-> 10, 10 <-> 2} and 
 {9 <-> 18, 18 <-> 13, 13 <-> 17, 17 <-> 9}.

So the problem is reduced to finding all admissible $k$-tuple $F$ of vertices in
$G_2=G-C_{1}-C_{2}$. This can be solved easily by Subsets.
Actual MMA session goes as follows:
G1=Graph[List[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],List[UndirectedEdge[1,2],UndirectedEdge[1,3],UndirectedEdge[1,4],UndirectedEdge[2,5],UndirectedEdge[4,5],UndirectedEdge[2,6],UndirectedEdge[2,7],UndirectedEdge[2,8],UndirectedEdge[2,10],UndirectedEdge[2,11],UndirectedEdge[2,12],UndirectedEdge[3,12],UndirectedEdge[3,13],UndirectedEdge[4,13],UndirectedEdge[5,14],UndirectedEdge[6,14],UndirectedEdge[13,14],UndirectedEdge[6,15],UndirectedEdge[7,15],UndirectedEdge[13,15],UndirectedEdge[7,16],UndirectedEdge[8,16],UndirectedEdge[13,16],UndirectedEdge[8,17],UndirectedEdge[9,17],UndirectedEdge[13,17],UndirectedEdge[9,18],UndirectedEdge[13,18],UndirectedEdge[10,19],UndirectedEdge[11,19],UndirectedEdge[11,20],UndirectedEdge[12,20],UndirectedEdge[13,20]],List[Rule[VertexLabels,List["Name"]],Rule[VertexCoordinates,List[List[Rational[2,5],Rational[1,10]],List[Rational[2,5],Rational[-2,5]],List[Rational[2,5],Rational[1,2]],List[Rational[1,10],Rational[3,10]],List[Rational[1,10],Rational[-1,10]],List[Rational[-1,10],Rational[-3,10]],List[Rational[-2,5],Rational[-1,2]],List[Rational[-7,10],Rational[-4,5]],List[Rational[-6,5],Rational[2,5]],List[Rational[9,10],Rational[-3,5]],List[Rational[11,10],Rational[1,10]],List[Rational[7,10],Rational[3,10]],List[Rational[-2,5],Rational[2,5]],List[Rational[-1,10],Rational[1,10]],List[Rational[-2,5],Rational[-1,5]],List[Rational[-7,10],Rational[-3,10]],List[Rational[-11,10],Rational[-1,10]],List[Rational[-9,10],Rational[3,5]],List[Rational[6,5],Rational[-3,10]],List[Rational[3,5],Rational[4,5]]]]]];


cycles = FindCycle[G1, Infinity, All]


cyclepairs = 
 Select[cycles, 
  Not[AcyclicGraphQ[
     VertexDelete[G1, VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[G1, #]]]]] &]


G0 = Subgraph[G1, Flatten[cyclepairs]];
HighlightGraph[G1, G0]


G2 = VertexDelete[G1, VertexList[G0]]


k = 10;
ans = Select[Subsets[VertexList[G2], {k}],
  Length[ConnectedComponents[VertexDelete[G1, #]]] == 2 &]


Length[ans]
(* 36 *)

Graph[G1, VertexSize -> ((# -> Large) & /@ #), 
   VertexStyle -> ((# -> Red) & /@ #), VertexLabels -> None] & /@ ans


