Iterating through the sublists to find all desired ones
Sometimes, the number of sublists can be too large, which may lead to memory crashes. I saw the following nice blog.
ClearAll[scanSubsetsChunks]
scanSubsetsChunks[f_, data_, nspec_:All, chunkLength_Integer?Positive] :=
    Module[
        {
            i = chunkLength + 1, 
            getChunk = 
                Quiet[
                    Subsets[data, nspec, {#, # + chunkLength - 1}],
                    Subsets::take
                ]&,
            chunk
        },
        chunk = Check[getChunk[1], Return[$Failed, Module]];
        While[chunk =!= {},
            f[chunk];
            chunk = getChunk[i];
            i += chunkLength;
        ]
    ]


(*use: scanSubsetsChunks[Print, Range[20], {5}, 3]*)

But I don’t know how to modify it. I want to iterate through it and then search for all desired sublists.
To give an example, I want to find all 5-sized subsets within the range 1..20 where the sum is greater than 15. I would like to ask how to modify the above function to achieve this goal.
For example:
{1,2,3,4,6}

is one that I wanted since $1+2+3+4+6=16>15$.

Does your definition of "subset" include duplicates, e.g. {1,1,1,1,1}? Because otherwise all subsets of length 5 except for the smallest one would have sum that exceeds 15. I.e. {1,2,3,4,5} is exactly 15 and any other 5-element subset from the range 1-20 would be greater than that.

In my definition, "subset" does not include duplicates.

You can avoid both chunking and pre-computing all of the subsets by using NextSubset or NextKSubset depending on what you mean by "subset". You can use these by loading the Combinatorica`  package or by using the resource functions:
Needs["Combinatorica`"];

With[
  {list = Range@20},
  NestList[NextKSubset[list, #] &, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 10]]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, 
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 4}, 
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 6}, 
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 7}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 8}, 
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 9}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 10}, 
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 11}} *)

The With is there to avoid computing the Range@20 each time, but that's probably not a huge expense compared to what you want to do. Of course, that just lists the subsets, but you could wrap NextKSubset with some function. In your case, you want to select, so you could perform a check on each.
Reap[
  With[
    {list = Range@20},
    Module[
      {current = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
      Do[
        If[15 < Total[current = NextKSubset[list, current]], Sow[current]],
        30]]]]
(* {Null, 
    {{{1, 1, 1, 1, 12}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 13}, 
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 14}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 15}, 
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 16}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 17}, 
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 18}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 19}, 
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 20}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 11}, 
      {1, 1, 1, 2, 12}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 13}}}} *)

Or if you want to stop after finding 5 cases (be careful to ensure that there will be at least 5 cases):
With[
  {list = Range@20},
  Module[
    {current = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
     kept = {}},
    Until[
      Length[kept] >= 5,
      If[15 < Total[current = NextKSubset[list, current]], AppendTo[kept, current]]];
    kept]]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1, 12}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 13}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 14}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 15}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 16}} *)

Replace NextKSubset with NextSubset if that matches your semantics better.
For Combinatorica documentation:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/NextKSubset.html
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/NextSubset.html
For the resource functions:
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NextKSubset/?i=NextKSubset&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NextSubset/?i=NextSubset&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch

Nice. However, since 'subset' does not include duplicates in my question, it would be great if you could provide another solution to exclude duplicates.

You may achieve this easier by using Scan and Sow/Reap. Here is an example with fewer data to make it simple:
d = Subsets[Range[6]];
Reap[
  Scan[(If[Total[#] > 15, Sow[#]]) &, d]][[2]]

{{{1, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4,
    6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 
   5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}}


Great! What if I only want to find the first 5 subsets that satisfy the condition (and stop as soon as they are found)?

I post a new question, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/309514/iterating-through-the-sublists-to-find-some-desired-sublists

Subsets have already been generated though, so I don't see how this avoids generating them.

I need some data for a simple example. You generated too many data for a simple example.

Thank you. The real problem arises from another issue(see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/309507/find-a-cyclic-vertex-cut-with-fixed-size) I’m working on, which involves finding special vertex cuts in a graph.
